# I'm having trouble computing a double integral in a probability question.

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

**The Question:**

> Two points are chosen randomly and independently on two adjacent sides of a square, connecting them splits the square into two parts, one of which is a right-angled triangle. What is the probability the resulting triangle's area will be less than $\tfrac16$th the area of the square?

**My Attempted Solution** 
 I started by defining k as the length of the side of the x And I decided the sides will be on the x and y axis respectively. $$X = \text{The first point's x value} \quad X \sim \mathrm{U}_{[0,k]}$$
$$Y = \text{The second point's y value} \quad Y \sim \mathrm{U}_{[0,k]}$$
since they're independent their shared pdf is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{k^2}$$
So solving then becomes:
$$P\left(0.5XY<\frac{k^2}{6}\right) = \iint_{xy< \frac{k^2}{3} } f_{X,Y}(x,y) dxdy $$
this is the point where I'm getting confused, my current attempt is to then do $$\int_{\frac{k}{3}}^{k} \int_{\frac{k}{3}}^{\frac{k^2}{3x}} \frac{1}{k^2} dy dx = \frac{\ln(3)}{3} -\frac{2}{9}$$
Based on a drawing of the region I'm integrating, but what I'm getting is not the right answer.
I'd love to get help with whether my approach is okay, and where did I go wrong

Comment: What triangle? And do you mean *at least* $\frac 16$, *at most* $\frac 16$ or something else entirely?

Comment: The triangle you get by connecting the two points

Comment: Connecting two points does not define a triangle.  Please edit your post for clarity.  We could make some guesses as to your meaning, but we might guess wrong  and why make your readers guess?

Comment: connecting two points within the square. you get a triangle and a trapeze thing

Comment: yes - two points and the origin the way I've defined the axis - the question just asks for a triangle though, and we get one by connecting the two points. I'll make an edit to clarify - also yes at most, my bad!

Comment: So, sticking with the unit square with lower left corner at the origin, let $x\in [0,1]$ and $y\in [0,1]$ be your choices.  The area of the triangle is then $\frac {xy}2$.  to have that be $≤\frac 16$  we want $y≤\frac 1{3x}$, so integrate $\min \left(1, \frac 1{3x}\right)$ from $0$ to $1$.  Then subtract from $1$ to get the probability that the area is $>\frac 16$.

Comment: What is the correct answer?

Comment: $\frac{\ln(3e)}{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've incorrectly set the bounds.

The region $$xy<\frac{k^2}{3}$$ is splitted into two regions:

1. $x$ from $0$ to $\frac{k}{3}$, then $y$ from $0$ to $k$.
2. $x$ from $\frac{k}{3}$ to $k$, then $y$ from $0$ to $\frac{k^2}{3x}$.

Comment: thank you - I've followed Lula's comment with the double integrals and the math checks out. I do think I understand as well y the two regions (or the minimum) - one x region is before the line $y=\frac{k^2}{3x}$ enters the square and one after it does. I don't understand though why x is bounded from 0 to k

Comment: like the way i understand it is with this schematic https://imgur.com/a/KXFGeue and according to it isn’t x bounded from k/3 to k? basically i understand region 2, but not the existence of region 1

Comment: I think I got it! I'll post my thoughts in a sec

Comment: Okay so $0<x<k \ 0<y<k \ 0<y<\frac{k^2}{3} \implies 0< y < \operatorname{min}(k,\frac{k^2}{3})$. We can then solve the inequality $k<\frac{k^2}{3}$ to find the two regions and we get your answer, which we use to construct the integrals. Thank you!

Comment: x from k/3 to k is the second region. The first region is from 0 to k/3 (before the upper bound of y is hyperbola).

Comment: Do you need a sketch?

Comment: no thanks! I think I understand enough to make one, i’d love if you could check it out to make sure I did it right though! https://imgur.com/a/PK1P896

Comment: @Lonimous , you're absolutely correct.